# Selenium problem dismissing pop-up window

Tags: c#, selenium

I have started creating a selenium script that needs to automate upload of files to a Wordpress site. So far it works to login! A pop-up window is then displayed. I need to automate closing this window. Here's my code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);        
IWebElement QuitGuide = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("graybutton"));
QuitGuide.Click();
```

this is the HTML element:

```
<graybutton class="normal mcg_quit_page">Quit Guide</graybutton>
```

If I add a breakpoint to this and step through using the debugger then it works fine. However, when I run it the Click method doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Based on your debugging observations, I wonder if your selenium script is trying to click the button too quickly. The act of debugging would force your script to slow down. Try adding `Thread.Sleep(30000)` before the `FindElement` and `Click` lines to force a 30 second pause. If that works, then you can work on a more robust solution using `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: the tagname is not likely to be "graybutton".  Post the HTML markup so we can see what you are trying to target here.  (Right-click choose, "inspect".)

Comment: I have posted the HTML markup, the tagname is "graybutton".

Comment: Putting Thread.sleep(30000) just gives me the error: "Thread does not exist in current context".

Comment: Jim, could You please post HTML code of the page?

Comment: Jim, you need to import the namespace. Try this code instead: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);`